# How to include NLog config files in code behind

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I have a `nlog.config` file with the following entry:

```xml
<include file="${basedir}/ActiveConfig/NLog/*.config"/>
```

But I want to solve this via code behind and have not found a method to do so.

```cs
LogManager.LoadConfiguration()
```

is overwriting my existing configuration.

Did I miss something?

Comment: You want to manually load several `.config` files and manually chain them together and create a single `LoggingConfiguration`-object ? (Without making use of `<include file=`)

Comment: Exactly. I don‘t want to use <include>

Comment: You can try and inherit from `XmlLoggingConfiguration` or `LoggingConfigurationParser`. Then you have access to protected methods like `LoadConfig` and `ParseNLogSection`

Comment: Alternative you can make a PullRequest https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pulls and introduce `LogManager.LoadConfiguration(LoggingConfiguration[] configs)`

Comment: Maybe a better pullrequest is adding a constructor to `XmlLoggingConfiguration` that takes a `string[]`-array of filenames.

Answer (score 2):

You could set it like this:

```cs
var config = XmlLoggingConfiguration
              .CreateFromXmlString("<include file='${basedir}/ActiveConfig/NLog/*.config' />");
LogManager.Configuration = config; // apply
```

Answer (score 1):

Think the easy solution is just to load all config-files into an in-memorystream, and then load that into a single `XmlLoggingConfiguration`:

```
var xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(memorystream);
NLog.LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(xmlReader, null);
```

Something like this, where you put the contents of all config-files within the same `<nlog>`-root:

```
<nlog>
   <!-- XML File 1 -->
   <targets>
   </targets>
   <rules>
   </rules>
   <! -- XML File 2 -->
   <targets>
   </targets>
   <rules>
   </rules>
</nlog>
```

If you want the AutoReload-feature working also, then this might work:

```
class MySpecialLoggingConfiguration : XmlLoggingConfiguration
{
    private string[] _fileNames;

    public MySpecialLoggingConfiguration(string[] fileNames)
    {
        _fileNames = fileNames;

        // Your special concat-logic in memory
    }

    public override LoggingConfiguration Reload()
    {
        return new MySpecialLoggingConfiguration(_fileNames);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<string> FileNamesToWatch => _fileNames;
}
```

Comment: And what about the `autoReload="true"` mechanism? If I merge them manual together, this is not working anymore. *each file has the `autoReload` flag set to `true`*

Comment: @DominicJonas Updated my answer to also cater for `autoReload="true"`